# c# add a PayPal donate button in application

Tags: c#, paypal

I want to add PayPal Donate button to my application, but I don't know how. I tried to search in google and on PayPal site, but I didn't found a solution. Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found solution on that site : http://www.gorancic.com/blog/net/c-paypal-donate-button :

```
private void btnDonate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "";

    string business     = "my@paypalemail.com";  // your paypal email
    string description  = "Donation";            // '%20' represents a space. remember HTML!
    string country      = "AU";                  // AU, US, etc.
    string currency     = "AUD";                 // AUD, USD, etc.

    url += "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" +
        "?cmd=" + "_donations" +
        "&business=" + business +
        "&lc=" + country +
        "&item_name=" + description +
        "&currency_code=" + currency +
        "&bn=" + "PP%2dDonationsBF";

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
}
```

Comment: Where can I find the required values for this url? I mean, I can guess my country string, but what about the other ones? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just FYI for @BtcSources and future readers: looks like you can also add `"&amount=" + amount` if you want a preset amount (e.g. `...&lc=US&amount=1.99&currency_code=USD.....`)