# Google Wallet send money url?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a C# desktop application and would like to have a couple buttons for users to click to pay for it. I found an easily-built URL for PayPal ([c# add a PayPal donate button in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401786/c-sharp-add-a-paypal-donate-button-in-application)) and I was wondering: does Google Wallet have any such thing?

[Note that I'm not using Android Pay - I'm just referring to Google Wallet's "send money" feature]

Comment: I recommend you look at the Google documentation for Google Wallet.

Comment: @Tim and where would I find this documentation? I see Android Pay documentation (and API), but not Google Wallet documentation

Comment: For people that look at this in the future, Google has just announced Google Pay (which will takeover Android Pay and Google Wallet in the future) and the API (Android & Web) can be found here: https://developers.google.com/payments/